# Что означает разбивка 'kind' в ответе геокодера?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Например, ввожу адрес "Москва, Таганская улица", он возвращает:
[image]

Что в данном случае означает первый "province" и второй "province". Как это по-разному можно назвать по-русски? Первый province это что, "Федеральный округ", а второй тогда что? Там написано "Москва". Значит город? Тогда если пойти дальше, то там есть "locality" и там тоже "Москва", выходит и там город и там город?

В документации по геокодеру не написано, в каком количестве может попадаться 'kind' с одинаковым именем типа 'province', но в документации к саджестам есть упоминание, что kind может вернуть ДВА компонента.

Тогда как быть с таким запросом "Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ, Салехард" он возвращает вот такой список компонентов:
[image]

тут аж целых три компонента 'province'. И как их понимать? Первый это все еще федеральный округ? Тогда второй это что это уже "область", а третий это "автономный округ"?

Можете объяснить? Спасибо.

Хочу понять как работает разбивка по компонентам kind и что каждый означает?

Comment: Это единицы регионального деления. Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ является частью Тюменской области, которая является частью Уральского федерального округа. А вообще этих компонентов может быть куда больше.

Comment: А есть пример запроса где очень много таких компонентов?

Comment: Адреса не только в разных странах отличаются, но даже в одной только России могут сильно розниться. Поскольку единого формата быть не может, структура ответа просто иерархическая. Может быть несколько одинаковых подтипов, может не быть некоторых, даже locality, который вроде как населённый пункт означает. Потому следует использовать или полный набор данных собранный последовательно, или частичный форматированный ответ, собранный самим Яндексом.